# theme chooser for cm 12 broken/disappeared after update?

Tags: cyanogenmod, settings, themes, sony-xperia-z1

On my Xperia Z1 compact and cm 12 I used the Dark Material theme. Then after a recent update it was disabled 'after too many app crashes'. I tried to set it again but now every time I go to settings->themes it exits with the error 'unfortunately, settings has stopped'.

Some posts on the web suggest that in settings->apps, clearing the data for the Theme Chooser app (under All Apps) will solve it. But there is no Theme Chooser app in my app list.

Is it possible to (re)install Theme Chooser somehow? Or another way to be able to switch Themes in cm 12?

phone: Sony Xperia Z1 compact (amami)
OS: cm 12.1 update 20160110
android: 5.1.1

EDIT

I tried (re)installing the Themes APK generously provided by the author of [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/nexus4/comments/3if9c2/someone_give_me_the_apk_of_cm121_theme_chooser/) post, but when I open the APK it first says "Do you want to install an update to this built-in application? Your existing data will not be lost. The updated application will get access to New|All", and when I choose either of those it exits with "App not installed."

That means that Theme Chooser is still on the phone. But why does it then not appear in the "All Apps" list (which would allow me to Clear Data)?

EDIT II

I dirty flashed the latest image (15/1) from the cyanogedmod website. Still no theme chooser that works.

Comment: Tell us whether these commands solve the issue: `adb shell su  -c am force-stop org.cyanogenmod.theme.chooser`; `adb shell su -c pm clear org.cyanogenmod.theme.chooser`; `adb shell su -c am force-stop org.cyanogenmod.themes.provider`; `adb shell su -c pm clear org.cyanogenmod.themes.provider` ; `adb reboot`;

Comment: Also, what does this return: `adb shell pm list packages -d`?

Comment: `adb shell su -c am force-stop org.cyanogenmod.theme.chooser` -> `unknown id: force-stop`. Same for the other force-stop command, and both `clear` commands return `unknown id: clear`.

Comment: The other command returns `package:org.cyanogenmod.wallpapers.photophase
package:com.android.camera2
package:com.google.android.launcher
package:com.google.android.gm
package:com.android.wallpaper.holospiral
package:com.android.phasebeam
package:org.cyanogenmod.themes.provider
package:com.cyanogenmod.wallpapers
package:org.cyanogenmod.theme.chooser
package:com.cyanogenmod.filemanager
package:com.android.musicvis
package:com.android.dreams.phototable
package:com.android.wallpaper.livepicker
package:com.android.email`

Comment: without `su -c` I can execute those first 4 commands, but after reboot I still get `Unfortunately, Settings has stopped`.

Comment: Ah. This does work with `su`: `adb shell su -c "am force-stop org.cyanogenmod.theme.chooser";` `adb shell su -c "pm clear org.cyanogenmod.theme.chooser";` `adb shell su -c "am force-stop org.cyanogenmod.themes.provider";` `adb shell su -c "pm clear org.cyanogenmod.themes.provider";` `adb reboot`. That boots to recovery. After just rebooting to CM, I still get get "Settings has stopped".

Comment: It looks like a factory reset is the only way to go... Some posts suggest clearing the data of themes, theme provider, and theme chooser? I cannot see any other processes called `*theme* `, even with `adb shell ps`?

Comment: Cleaning `trebuchet` did not help either. It was OK again after a clean flash all was good. I felt like an iPhone user though.

Comment: trebuchet is the launcher app of CM. Why did you think clearing its data would help?

Comment: Stuck for ideas I guess - and thought it interacted with the theme manager.

Comment: I see. Can you sum up your solution into an answer? That would be easier for others to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using `adb` to remove the data for the packages `org.cyanogenmod.theme.chooser` and `org.cyanogenmod.themes.provider`, as suggested above and [elsewhere](http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/96000-anyone-else-having-trouble-with-the-new-theme-engine), and also after cleaning the data in `trebuchet` on the phone (by way of trial and error), the only thing that really made the Theme Chooser work again was a clean flash:

- download the latest [cyanogenmod](http://download.cyanogenmod.org) (and [Google Apps](https://github.com/opengapps/arm/releases) if you want) to your sd card (remove `/system/*` too if you are switching to Open GApps from another GApps)
- reboot into recovery (on an Xperia Z1 Compact by repeatedly pressing volume-up at boot)
- choose `wipe data / factory reset` and empty cache
- do `install update` for both the CM and GApps ZIP files
- reboot

After reboot, my apps were re-installed via my Google account and the data (images, documents) from before flashing were all still there.

The custom wallpapers and (in my case no) sounds needed to be set anew.